# Eclipse Luna - "No projects are found to import"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-luna

I am using the following version of Eclipse IDE:

```
Eclipse SDK
Version: Luna SR2 (4.4.2)
Build id: M20150204-1700
```

I have checked out my code using SVN and when I do the following:

Import > general > Existing Projects into Workspace > click on project

I get the error:

```
"No projects are found to import"
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: is this a maven project?

Comment: No an Ant project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that release, the wizard expects to find `.project` files defining the projects. If they were not checked in, you can not use that wizard. You have more options under the current release, Oxygen.2, and unless you have a reason to be using a 3 year old version, I'd suggest updating and using the new "Open Projects from File System" wizard.